# get size of list struct in struct

Tags: c

I have following structs:

```
struct Student{
 char *name;
 int age;
};
struct Class{
 char *class_name;
 struct Student students[];
};
```

And a counting function  :

```
int countStdInClass(struct Class *classA){
  int sizeOfStd = sizeof(classA->students)/sizeof(classA->students[0])
  return sizeOfStd ;
}
```

When compiling ,an error occurrence :

```
invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct Student[]'
```

Please help me correct it .
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** In `struct Class` -

```
struct Student students[ ];
 /*                     ^ you haven't given any size .  */
```

You need to give number of elements as you use it as operand to `sizeof` . Example -

```
struct Student students[5];    // give any desired size
```

**2.** Also in your function `int countStdInClass`-

```
int sizeOfStd = sizeof(classA->students)/sizeof(classA->students[0])
 /*                                                                 ^ ; missing   */
```

Comment: This is a flexible array member, he doesn't need to state a fixed size.

Comment: @Lundin  Not even when he needs it as operand of `sizeof` ? Then probably he don't need fixed array member .

Comment: @ameyCU It doesn't make any sense to use sizeof together with flexible array members.

Comment: @Lundin Well , yes . If he wants to use `sizeof` , then fixed array member is unnecessary . He will need to specify size.

Comment: @ameyCU Well, he needs to actually know what he is doing... I'll have to assume so. If it turns out he doesn't have a clue about flexible array members but is just playing "guess the syntax", then no amount of advise given will help.

Comment: In my comments I mistakenly refered as _fixed_  , it is _flexible_ . Sorry for that . I meant flexible array members there.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard explicitly states (6.7.2.1) that a flexible array member isn't counted when taking the `sizeof` the struct:

> In particular, the size of the structure is as if the flexible array
>   member were omitted except that it may have more trailing padding than
>   the omission would imply.

It only makes sense to use flexible array members if you allocate memory dynamically. And as for all other cases of dynamic memory, it doesn't make any sense to use the `sizeof` operator on the allocated segment.

When using the flexible array member `students`, you have to allocate memory as:

```
struct Class* c = malloc( sizeof(*c) + n*sizeof(struct Student) );
```

Meaning you already know the size! It is `n*sizeof(struct Student)`.